# How to solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've written this java application to respond the data from the command line  and store it into a database :

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.*;


public class Program {


    public static void main(String[] args)throws ClassNotFoundException 


    {


        Connection conn=null;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/DevOps_DB","root","root");


             PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pers " + "VALUES ('"+args[0]+"'); ");
             st.executeUpdate();


        } 



        catch (SQLException ex) {

            System.out.println("SQL Exception : "+ ex.getMessage());

            System.out.println("Vendor Error : "+ ex.getErrorCode());

        }


        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();


        }



//      
//      for(String arg : args)            
//      {   
//           System.out.println(arg);            
//      }




    }





}
```

But I've got the following exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at Program.main(Program.java:18)
```

why ? ... any help to fix the problem ?

**EDIT :**

I added the .jar file , see the following image :

[image]

Comment: Well how are you running this? How are you making the MySQL JDBC driver available to Java?

Comment: Check if required classes are in your classpath

Comment: is mysql driver in your classpath?

Comment: @kent :see my edit :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet see my edit :)

Comment: You say you've "added" the jar file - have you added it to the build path?

Comment: yes into the build path and befor runing the program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download [mysql connector jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html) file(driver implementation) and add it to your class path.

On the side note if your are using JDBC 4.0 (Java 7 and even 6 I think) then you need not use `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`. Simply add the jar to the class path. Driver implementation will automatically be searched and loaded from class path.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding it to the same project you are running. `Right Click the project -- > build path -- > configure build path` and `In Libraries Tab press Add External Jar and Select your jar.`

Comment: As the Exception clearly suggests class loading failed as class was not located I would suggest use `java -cp pathToMySqlCJar yourMainClass` to run and see. If this succeeds you are adding not adding jar to your project correctly. Try Rebuilding your project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

ok you added the jar.do one thing open server,
form window->show view->servers
then double click on server

then it will open a new window then goto open Launch configuration then

go to class path and agin add mysql-connector.jar click on ok.

Answer (score 3):

You have to download mysql connector jar file(driver implementation) and add it to your class path.

Answer (score 2):

@Akari : this is related to the .jar file for MySql. Try to check whether the .jar for MySql is set to the classpath or not.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the mysql driver which you can download from [a link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html)!
and copy the .jar file of the mysql zip and paste it here in "lib"[Screenshot of the location u have to paste in into (in the interface)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJvdZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Answer (score -1):

I had a proplem same. Then i moved file .jar from (D:) to (C:) and it ư

Comment: Your answer seems to be incomplete, but it's also not very insightful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31427507)